# C#: Get distinct T from IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

Assuming one has the object `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, what is the most concise way to get a list of distinct T from this object?

Sample code:

```
var listOfLists = new List<List<string>>();

listOfLists.Add(new string[] {"a", "b", "c", "c"}.ToList());
listOfLists.Add(new string[] {"a", "f", "g", "h"}.ToList());
listOfLists.Add(new string[] {"j", "k", "l"}.ToList());

List<string> distinctList = listOfLists.MagicCombinationOfEnumerableMethods();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", distinctList));
```

Output would be something like:

```
a, b, c, f, g, h, j, k, l
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Projects each element of a sequence to an IEnumerable and flattens
>   the resulting sequences into one sequence

```
List<string> distinctList = listOfLists.SelectMany(r => r).Distinct().ToList();
```

You can also modify your code for adding elements in list like:

```
listOfLists.Add(new List<string> {"a", "b", "c", "c"});
```

instead of creating an array and then converting it to list.